# "InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype variant to a NumPy array" - environment related issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, environment, pytorch-geometric

**This is an environmental related issue where the code doesn't run on the local environment, the code runs in virtual environments but I can't train on virtual environments so I want to be able fix my local environment.**
I am making in a Graph Neural Network with torch_geometric and I am trying to run the training loop which has for loop inside the loop for all the epochs:

```
for data in progress_bar:
```

where

```
progress_bar=tqdm(train_loader, desc=f"Epoch {i}")
```

in which `train _loader` is a torch_geometric Dataloader object

```
pyg.loader.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=params["batch_size"], shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=2)
```

that loads the `pyg.data.Dataset` subclass object `train_dataset`. I have also been converting tensorflow tensors to torch tensors when preprocessing the raw dataset as it was .tfrecord (edit: it's confirmed now that this operation is done correctly)

The `train_loader` is instantiated as

```
train_dataset = OneStepDataset(data_path, "train", noise_std=params["noise"])
train_loader = pyg.loader.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=params["batch_size"], shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=2)
```

here is a mcve (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZFWhKME5eK77SBJFfisWzRBG1ZtcGHyN?usp=sharing) which doesn't actually recreate the error but the local environment still produces the error when performing the same task. Any suggestions on possible environment-related issues?
The following is my pip freeze:**

```
absl-py==1.4.0
aiosignal==1.3.1
asttokens==2.2.1
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==22.2.0
backcall==0.2.0
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
comm==0.1.2
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==5.1.1
distlib==0.3.6
dm-tree==0.1.8
entrypoints==0.4
executing==1.2.0
filelock==3.9.0
flatbuffers==23.1.21
frozenlist==1.3.3
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.16.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.51.1
h5py==3.8.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
importlib-resources==5.10.2
install==1.3.5
ipykernel==6.20.2
ipython==8.8.0
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.2.0
jsonschema==4.17.3
jupyter-client==7.4.9
jupyter-core==5.1.5
keras==2.11.0
libclang==15.0.6.1
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
msgpack==1.0.4
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
numpy==1.24.1
oauthlib==3.2.2
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.4.0
pkgutil-resolve-name==1.3.10
platformdirs==2.6.2
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
protobuf==3.19.6
psutil==5.9.4
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
Pygments==2.14.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.19.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pywin32==305
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==25.0.0
ray==2.2.0
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.0
six==1.16.0
stack-data==0.6.2
svgwrite==1.4.3
tensorboard==2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.11.0
tensorflow-intel==2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.30.0
termcolor==2.2.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
torch==1.13.1
torch-cluster==1.6.0+pt113cpu
torch-geometric==2.2.0
torch-scatter==2.1.0+pt113cpu
torch-sparse==0.6.16+pt113cpu
torch-spline-conv==1.2.1+pt113cpu
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.64.1
traitlets==5.8.1
typing-extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.17.1
wcwidth==0.2.6
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wrapt==1.14.1
zipp==3.11.0
```

I am using `Python 3.8.10` which is the same version on google colab.
I tried installing python and all dependencies for this code, same error occurred.

The google colab environment has

```
tensorflow==2.9.2
numpy==1.21.6
torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116/torch-1.13.1%2Bcu116-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
torch_geometric @ https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html
```

Comment: I tried iterating through the dataloader without tqdm, it pops the same error

Comment: I tried various ways to iterate through the dataloader but it pops the same error when trying to iterate so I can't seem to print this.

Comment: Some more context the error happens actually originates from the [ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py) submodule, when trying to convert the tensor to numpy.

Comment: Just an update, I was able to make a mcve but it works fine so I believe the problem is to do with the environment. Any suggestions for possible issues with the environment that could cause such issues?

Comment: I just added my packages to the post. Also, I confirmed the problem to be environment related by running the exact same code that worked on google colab on a separate python file on my computer and ending up with the same error.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your setup? Are you running on Mac M1/M2, Windows or Linux? If possible, kindly add the full traceback.

Comment: Also the Colab example doesn't install `reading_utils`, could you elaborate how to install it?